# TCL pattern matching with / and [ ]

Tags: tcl

I am using following to match strings with characters like /, [, ] and the same string passed in 2 varibles are shown different.

```
set a "a/b/c[1]"
set b "a/b/c[1]"

if {[regexp $a $b]} {
   puts "match"
} else {
   puts "no match"
}
```

Output is "no match"

What is the fix here?

Comment: The first two lines are usually syntax errors. Apart from that, bracketed sequences are special to regular expressions (denoting character sets to match).

Comment: `/` is not a special character at all here, BTW.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check if two variables are equal, `regexp` is not the right tool. You can use `string equal $a $b`, or `if {$a eq $b} ...`.

If you want the `regexp` feature that a match may happen anywhere inside the string, then you can make `regexp` do a literal match: `regexp (?q)$a $b`.

However, if you want to do **pattern** matching, as the title of your question says, then you have to take the rules of the pattern matching command into account.

Answer (score 0):

This is a trick I use sometimes to handle square braces... maybe helps, maybe not:

```
set rb {[}
set lb {]}
set a "a/b/c${rb}1${lb}"
set b "a/b/c${rb}1${lb}"
# as stated above, string equal is what you want here, not regexp
if {[string equal $a $b]} {
   puts "match"
} else {
   puts "no match"
}
# => match
put $a
# =>a/b/c[1]
```